How to calculate offset for the Stake Program in getProgramAccounts for a validtor info account?
I'm trying to create a filter that will return the associated validator info account for a provided validator pubkey. How do I structure the json params passed to getProgramAccounts?
I've been able to return all validator info accounts like this:
[
"Config1111111111111111111111111111111111111",
{
"encoding": "jsonParsed"
}
]
But I'm not sure how to filter based on a validator pubkey (not the pubkey of the info account, rather the validator pubkey associated with it).

Currently, there is no tool to calculate offset, because account data contains only raw bytecode without metadata.
Not sure, but in your case offset should be 124 bytes:
RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp::new_base58_encoded(124, vote_account_pubkeys[0].as_ref()))


Great, thanks. How did you figure out what the offset should be? I'd like to understand so I can run other types of queries in the future.
